# Issue with NetLogo map

Tags: netlogo

When I enter `(map [?1 + ?2] [1 2 3] [2 4 6])` into the command center, it works fine. But when I enter this code

```
to test
  (map [?1 + ?2] [1 2 3] [2 4 6])
end
```

I get the diagnostic: "Expected command." with `map` highlighted. I'm stumped. Suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

(I'm using NetLogo 5.1.0.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `map` is not considered a command (as the diagnostic says). When I replace `map` with `foreach` (and put the function at the end) it's fine.

In fact, that's what I really wanted in the first place. I was using `map` for it's side-effects of running through multiple lists rather than to return a list.  My mistake.

Comment: you should add this as an edit to your question, not as an answer

Answer (score 2):

For user convenience, the command center allows you to set the "context" of your commands and does a little extra interpretation depending on that context.  The problem is not that the `map` reporter is failing, but that it reports a list, and you need a command saying what to do with that list.

After you enter `(map [?1 + ?2] [1 2 3] [2 4 6])` in the command center, look not just at the result but also at the code actually executed (right above the result).  If you put that code in your `test` procedure, it will work.

Comment: By "does a little extra interpretation" do you just mean "prepends `show` to reporter expressions"?

Comment: Pretty much.  But for example, if you set the command center context to `turtles`, then entering reporter `rpt` at the command line will be interpreted as `ask turtles [show rpt]`.

Answer (score 1):

you code does not work because you are producing a new list with map but you are not assigning that list to any variable. You are right that map is not a command primitive, it is a reporter primitive, so it returns a value and you have to put that value somewhere, like print it on the screen:

```
to test
    print (map [?1 + ?2] [1 2 3] [2 4 6])
end
```

or store it in a variable:

```
to test
    let a-variable (map [?1 + ?2] [1 2 3] [2 4 6])
    print a-variable
end
```